# Are WebObjects frameworks included in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, webobjects

I read here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Major_features that

> As of Xcode 3.0, Apple dropped
>   WebObjects development inside Xcode;
>   WOLips should be used instead. Xcode 3
>   still includes the WebObjects
>   frameworks.

Can somebody tell me if the WebObjects frameworks are included with Xcode 4? Or, are there other reasons why I should use Xcode 3 instead of Xcode 4 for the maintenance of my old WO project? And if you have some info on the use of WOLips, then I'd like to know. My Mac is running OSX 10.6.7.

Answer (score 4):

The WebObjects frameworks are not installed with Xcode 4 (or Xcode 3 for that matter). You really should switch to WOLips. Yes, Eclipse is ugly, but it's a far better Java IDE than Xcode.

Check the WOCommunity wiki for details:

http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/display/WO/WO+5.4+Getting+Started

Answer (score 2):

WOLips is a plugin for the Eclipse Java IDE.  You don't use Xcode at all.  Apple doesn't either.  EVERYONE uses Eclipse with the WOLips plugin (as far as I know at least).  No, it's not as polished as Apple products, but it has lots of Java goodies and WOLips is extremely well supported, as is Project Wonder and the whole community.

Follow the link to the wiki that Pascal provided, and you'll find lots of information.  There are also webobjects mailing lists such as webobjects-dev.

If it was yesterday, I would have said to get even MORE information, go to WOWODC next weekend in Montreal and get to know many of the people behind all this.  But I think registration ended yesterday.

Good luck!